# What is the best approach in structuring user testing for a task list design?

Tags: usability-testing, ux-designer, prototype, testing

When using my new task list design, the user will need to complete 5 individual nest steps to complete their account. I want to evaluate in my user testing how successful the user will complete these steps.

Ideally I would want the user to look at my task list design and know that these are the next steps that they will need to complete.

I am wondering what is the best approach to structuring the scenarios in my testing so I can understand if completing these steps are intuitive for the user. They do not need to complete these is order.

Would I ask for example, "What will be your next steps? and see if they will start completing the next 5 steps one after the other automatically with little help? The issue with this is I will be testing on a prototype that might not intuitively link to the next step.

Or would I break down the steps into the 5 individual scenarios for the user but this seems as if I am helping the user complete the test and giving them emphasis that they would not necessarily have in the real world.

[image: Tasks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map it to the real world task the user would need to do, think about the business scenario and only that. Would it be 5 separate tasks or only one?
If it is one, stick to one scenario. You could detail the tasks a bit, but also think in business concepts and parts of the business process. Your task lists UI has to match the real world patterns and if you have to add some system-related, not business value related tasks or steps, you need to take it back to the drawing board before you do the test.
Good luck!